# Error When trying to add Customer to Database (syntax error in insert into statement oledb vb net)

Tags: sql, database, vb.net, syntax-error

I am doing a college assignment and have been trying to figure it out for hours, but I cant seem to get my new customer to save to the database! Please, I would really, REALLY apreciate it if you could have a look at my code, make any suggestions, or let me know more efficient ways of doing this. Bellow I provide a sample of my code for this.

To begin with, on form load I determine the new customer ID to be put into the database:

```
Private Sub frmRegister_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'Me.CustomerTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatabasePizzaPalaceDataSet.Customer)

    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Year 2\Unit 17 Project Planning\Workto do\PizzaPalce\Program\DatabasePizzaPalace.accdb"

    conn.Open()

    Dim Rows As Integer
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customer"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)

    da.Fill(ds, "Customer")

    Rows = ds.Tables("Customer").Rows.Count

    NewCustomerID.Text = Rows + 1

    Customer_IDTextBox.Text = NewCustomerID.Text

    conn.Close()

End Sub
```

Now that being said, here is the piece of code I run when clicking on my save button for the recrod to be added through a new data row.

```
Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click

    Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection()
    conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=H:\Year 2\Unit 17 Project Planning\Workto do\PizzaPalce\Program\DatabasePizzaPalace.accdb"
    conn.Open()

    Dim inc As Integer
    Dim sql As String = "SELECT * FROM Customer"
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter(sql, conn)
    da.Fill(ds, "Customer")
    inc = Customer_IDTextBox.Text

    If inc <> -1 Then

        Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)

        Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

        dsNewRow = ds.Tables("Customer").NewRow()

        dsNewRow.Item("Customer_ID") = Customer_IDTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Username_Email") = Username_EmailTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Password") = PasswordTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("First_Name") = First_NameTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Surname") = SurnameTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("Mobile") = MobileTextBox.Text
        dsNewRow.Item("House") = HouseTextBox.Text

        ds.Tables("Customer").Rows.Add(dsNewRow)

        da.Update(ds, "Customer")

        MsgBox("New Record added to the Database")

        conn.Close()

        frmLogin.Show()

    End If

    'Dim cb As New OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder(da)


    'Me.CustomerTableAdapter.Insert(Customer_IDTextBox.Text, Username_EmailTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text, First_NameTextBox.Text, SurnameTextBox.Text, MobileTextBox.Text, HouseTextBox.Text)
    'Me.CustomerTableAdapter.Fill(Me.DatabasePizzaPalaceDataSet.Customer)
    'Me.Validate()
    'Me.CustomerBindingSource.EndEdit()
        'Me.CustomerTableAdapter.Fill(DatabasePizzaPalaceDataSet.Customer)
        'Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.DatabasePizzaPalaceDataSet)

    'da.Update(ds, "Customer")

    'MsgBox("You have been succesfully registerd with us. Thanks!")

    'conn.Close()

    'frmLogin.Show()
End Sub
```

In comments you can also see a code provided by my teacher, which we are supposed to improve, I just wish to find a way of making this work!

Thanks a lot, all help and suggestions are very appreciated.

Comment: I am not sure, I am trying to follow this tutorial to commit changes to Database - http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/NET/nets12p10.html

Comment: However, the command builder and the update should do the saving

Comment: I misread the documentation. I'll take another look.

Comment: Are you certain that `"Customer"` is the name of the table inside your dataset? I tried your code and it worked for me. When you are debugging, is the code actually getting inside your `IF Then Else` statement?

Comment: Hmm strange, it is customer both inside the database and also that is how I am naming the dataset...not sure if that causes confusion to the program?

Comment: It does get into it as it highlights my line where I update (da.update(ds, "customer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ds.Tables("Customer")` I used `ds.Tables(0)` (or whatever index your table is at inside your `DataSet`.)

```
    Dim con As New OleDbConnection(_myConn) ''_myConn should be your connection string
    con.Open()
    Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from customer", con)
    da.Fill(ds)

    Dim cb As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    Dim dsNewRow As DataRow

    dsNewRow = ds.Tables(0).NewRow()
    dsNewRow.Item(1) = "1"
    dsNewRow.Item(2) = "Blah"
    dsNewRow.Item(3) = "Test"
    dsNewRow.Item(4) = "T"
    dsNewRow.Item(5) = "T"
    dsNewRow.Item(6) = "T"
    dsNewRow.Item(7) = "20000101"

    ds.Tables(0).Rows.Add(dsNewRow)
    da.Update(ds.Tables(0))

    con.Close()
```

It's important to realize your database schema also. If your first column is an identity auto increment column, you want to avoid trying to insert anything to that column. I prefer to use the Indexes because it's a lot easier to misspell a column name as a string, although it may not be as clear.

So, `Customer_ID` may be (or not be) an auto-increment field, which means trying to insert data into that column will result in an error.

Comment: My database does not use auto incremented keys, but used to, I will just create the program again copy paste the code and create new connection, I'll let you know how.it goes thanks for all

Comment: No problem. Just make sure the data types are correct. This code works for me, so as long as your connection is correct and you are inserting the correct data types/number of fields into the database it should work.

Comment: I am getting the same error, I am referring to the tables as per index instead of names and same on items, but error when trying to update...I have had a look at my database before doing this, it is set to numbers, although it does have a primary key in place and relationships already on the database. Then I just created a new solution, copied and pasted old code created new connection, and just edited the code to what is here and nothing,However, thanks a lot for your help it helps me know a bit more about what could be going on and how it all works, let me know if you got any other ideas.

Comment: When you say " it is set to numbers, " what do you mean?

Comment: Let me expand on data types. So if `Customer_ID` is a `Number` field in the database, you need to wrap your textbox value like this: `CInt(Customer_IDTextBox.Text)`. This converts the string value from the textbox to the data type that the database is holding/expecting.

Comment: Sorrry for the stupuid question, but how do I "wrap it"? where? I am pretty sure that is the solution to the problem perhaps

Comment: `dsNewRow.Item("Customer_ID") = Customer_IDTextBox.Text`.. If `Customer_ID` is a `Number` field, you should write.. `dsNewRow.Item("Customer_ID") = CInt(Customer_IDTextBox.Text)` .. and the same goes for the rest of the fields. [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2dy91zy.aspx) for more conversion types.

Comment: I am really sorry haha, but I keep getting the same Error :/ fml haha But thanks for all really helps me a lot

Comment: Syntax ERROR in INSERT INTO statement

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20053084/syntax-error-in-update-statement-while-access-database-in-vb-net).. Also, let me see your `insert` statement error.

Comment: OMG It worked!! Haha thanks man, I really apreciate your help, seriously my brain was melting! Best in life brother :)

Comment: Haha, no problem bud. Good luck with the rest of your stuff. Sorry it took so long!